# Outlook for windows automatically adds teams meeting after importing ics event

Tags: windows, outlook, icalendar

I'm having a problem importing a `ics` file generated by our application - but the issue is ONLY with importing into Microsoft Outlook for Windows. All other calendars (Apple Calendar, Google Calendar, Outlook for Mac, Microsoft Calendar) import the event correctly.

Since we added the `ORGANIZER` property to our event, Outlook automatically generates a meeting for Microsoft Teams and requires invitations to it before it can be saved to the calendar: unexpected behavior since we want the event to be saved directly to the calendar once the import is confirmed.

[image]

It is not possible for me to remove the `ORGANIZER` property from our event since it is needed to later create an event that can delete the event itself (this logic is needed to achieve the feature requirements).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.5

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:OTB:73dbafa9-1519-49fa-b812-70776e16b0e7
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:73dbafa9-1519-49fa-b812-70776e16b0e7
DTSTART:20230501T065000Z
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTEND:20230501T070000Z
LOCATION:Localtion
SUMMARY:Service
ATTENDEE;CUTTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=OPT-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=Quent
 in Stewart:japi@mailinator.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Informationen zum Termin:\nNachname: Stewart\nVorname: Quentin\
 nE-Mail-Adresse: japi@mailinator.com\nTelefonnummer: +1 571919-9139\nAkten
 zeichen: 568\nBemerkungen: In et ut ullamco par\nTeilnehmer/in Anzahl: 7\n
ORGANIZER;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:foo@bar.com
DTSTAMP:20230424T130240Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The library used to create the `ics` file is:

https://github.com/markuspoerschke/iCal

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

I tried looking for a specific setup for Outlook for Windows and we tried disabling this setting but nothing.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/make-every-meeting-online-70f9bda0-fd29-498b-9757-6709cc1c73f0#OS_Type=Windows

I removed several properties like:

```
ROLE:REQ-PARTICIPANT
PARTSTAT:NEEDS-ACTION
RSVP:TRUE
X-NUM-GUESTS:0:mailto:segoxebowy@mailinator.com
```

but nothing